# Mock method with Consumer

Tags: java, lambda, mocking

I want to mock `repository.actionOnFile(String path, Consumer<InputStream> action)` in this source:

```
@Autowired
private FileRepositoryService repository;

public Document getDocument(URL url) {
    MutableObject<Document> obj = new MutableObject<>();
    Consumer<InputStream> actionOnFile = inputStream -> obj.setValue(getDocument(inputStream));
    try {
        repository.actionOnFile(url.toExternalForm(), actionOnFile);
    } catch (S3FileRepositoryException e) {
        throw e.getCause();
    }
    return obj.getValue();
}
```

The problem is that the second argument is a lambda expression.

How to mock it with mockito, I need to pass to the `accept` method  the input stream to test it?

Comment: You may want to refactor your service to accept a `Function<InputStream, R>` and to return `R`. I assume you made into consumer to close input stream after, but your problem is exactly what happens when your services rely on some side effect to produce any result.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found solution!

```
doAnswer(ans -> {
    Consumer<InputStream> callback = ans.getArgument(1, Consumer.class);
    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream("test".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    callback.accept(stream);
    return null;
}).when(repository).actionOnFile(eq("any"), any(Consumer.class));
```

Comment: I think you should accept your own answer. Although it's not pretty, this is what you need to do to also test the actionOnFile consumer that you have defined inline in the getDocument method

Comment: please suggest prettier solution )

Comment: Sorry about that, I don't know either. It isn't a very natural thing to write this with Mockito. In my project, I moved all the messy code to a separate function and gave it a pretty name :)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to mock the Function argument then the following would work:

```
Mockito.when(convertStringtoInt(Mockito.any(String.class), Mockito.any(Consumer.class))).then[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to mock it with mockito, I need to pass in accept method test
>   input stream?

In your case, you want to test the `getDocument()` method.
So what you need to mock is the dependency of the class under test :
that is the `repository` field.
`actionOnFile.add()` more specifically should be mocked.
According to your code, either the method should throw `S3FileRepositoryException`  or it provokes a side effect not visible in the code.

In the exception scenario, you should write something as :

```
 Mockito.when(fileRepositoryServiceMock.actionOnFile(url.toExternalForm(), actionOnFile)).thenThrow(new S3FileRepositoryException(cause));
```

And in the successfull, you should just verify that the method is invoked :

```
 Mockito.verify(fileRepositoryServiceMock).actionOnFile(url.toExternalForm(), actionOnFile));
```

Mocking a `Consumer` is really not a big deal.
It is a interface, you can mock any interface with Mockito.

The real issue is actually the `Consumer` makes not part of the API of the tested method.
It is a local variable.
Besides, it relies on an `inputStream` field that is not show in the code.
You cannot and have not to mock internal things.
Note that it also relies on a overloaded `getDocument()` method that is not mocked.
 So you would need to provide a consistent `InputStream` if you want to  `getDocument()` that accepts a inputStream doesn't throw an exception.

Long story short : I think that you should either rethink your design to extract the depending processings in another class or write an integration test.