# Unable to cover Consumer function in code coverage for ReceiverOptions.addAssignListener()

Tags: java, apache-kafka, junit, mocking, project-reactor

I have been trying to increase code coverage on this particular piece of code for a while but can't seem to figure it out. This private method is invoked from within a public method. The public method is called as shown below. My understanding is that since subscription to the topics happens later, there are no partitions that are assigned, therefore when unit testing, that Consumer within `addAssignListener()` is never invoked.

```
class someClass {
    public ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate somePublicMethod(Set<String> topics) {
      // ...
      ReceiverOptions<Object, Object> receiverOptions = somePrivateMethod(customConsumerProperties);
      receiverOptions = receiverOptions.subscription(topics);
      return new ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<>(receiverOptions);
    }


    private ReceiverOptions<Object, Object> somePrivateMethod(Map<String, Object> customConsumerProperties) {

      boolean featureFlag = someConfig.isEnabled();

      ReceiverOptions<Object, Object> basicReceiverOptions = ReceiverOptions.create(customConsumerProperties);

      basicReceiverOptions = basicReceiverOptions.addAssignListener(partitions -> {
        partitions.forEach(receiverPartition -> Mono.just(receiverPartition)
            .doOnNext(receiverPartition1 -> {
              if (featureFlag) {
                receiverPartition1.seekToTimestamp(someConfig.getStartTimestamp());
              }
            })
            .subscribe());
      });

      return basicReceiverOptions;
    }

  }
```

The Unit Test

```
@Test
  void test() {
    // ...
    ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<String, String> template = someClass.somePublicMethod(Set.of("sample-topic"));
    assertNotNull(template);
  }
```

How can I unit test those particular lines of code?

I tried manually invoking the [assignment](https://projectreactor.io/docs/kafka/1.0.0.M3/api/reactor/kafka/receiver/ReceiverOptions.html#assignment-java.util.Collection-) and [mocking the Consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47224185/mock-method-with-consumer) but no luck.